# Find in string a specific word + whatever word + specific word python

Tags: python, regex, string, find

I would like to find in a string, a combination of words where some/most words are specific but one could be anything (any word, character).

```
sentence = 'There are five cats and seven dogs at the park.'

find_in_string = 'cats and ... dogs'

if find_in_string in sentence:
   print(find_in_string)
```

I understand that regex could be implemented at this point, but exactly what and how is a bit confusing, so Thank You!

Comment: So you want to match `cats` and `dogs` in the same string? Does order matter `dogs` then `cats`? Is your `find_in_string` actually multiple words - if so, how do we decide which ones must be in the sentence? Are we removing duplicates from the string (e.g. the `.` character shows up 3 times, but doesn't appear 3 times in the string)? Are we using the `find_in_string` variable as if it's a list of words to match against? This question is very broad.

Comment: @ctwheels Thank you for asking questions, I'm afraid I wasn't specific enough. 1. yes, in the same string. 2. the order matters. 3. between the 'and' and 'dogs' should be only one word (in this case seven).

Comment: Then you can try `cats and \S+ dogs`

Comment: Or even [`cats and \w+ dogs`](https://regex101.com/r/TOjOQ3/1) where `\w` is a [short](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

Comment: @ctwheels for this to work in this way, how should I write it - right now this doesn't work. `find_in_string = r'cats and \S+ dogs'` `if find_in_string in sentence: print(find_in_string)`

Comment: @okay123 you can use `re.search` to get the match, if a match occurred, print it.

Comment: Alright, thank you! :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you!

```
sentence ='There are five cats and seven dogs at the park.'
find_in = re.search(r'cats and \S+ dogs', sentence)
if find_in:
    print(find_in)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `.` operator which is a wildcard for any character. For example, in your example you could write the expression

```
r'cats and .+ dogs`
```

That's saying "look for the string `cats and` (note the space), then any characters at all until there's another space followed by `dogs`". If you wanted to restrict the characters that match between the `and` and `dogs`, you could use something like `[a-z]` instead of just `.` to restrict the matching to lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. You can use re for this

```
import re
>>> re.findall(r"cats and.*dogs", sentence)
['cats and seven dogs']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.search` and use `.*` for a wildcard:

```
sentence = 'There are five cats and seven dogs at the park.'
find = re.search(r'cats and .*dogs', sentence)
if find:
    print(find[0])
```

Prints:

```
'cats and seven dogs'
```